# Unable to insert values into database using ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, soap

I don't know why I am getting an error when I am calling the ajax method . The web service is working fine . I have hosted in my local machine and checked . Any help is greatly appreciated.

Web Service Code:

```
public class Contacts : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public void InsertIntoContacts(string name,string email,string message)
    {

        string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KarthikDBConnString"].ConnectionString;
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Insert into contacts values(@name , @email , @message)");
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", message);
        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

The html markup for the form is:

```
<form role="form" id="contactForm">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Name" id="name" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email :</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Email here (optional)" id="email" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="message">Message :</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Enter your message here" id="message"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="sendMsgBtn" onclick="javascript:SendMsg()">Send Message</button>
</div>
</form>
```

And the ajax call is :

```
    function SendMsg() {
    var soapRequset = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">\
  <soap:Body>\
    <InsertIntoContacts xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">\
      <name>'+$("#name").val()+'</name>\
      <email>'+$("#email").val()+'</email>\
      <message>'+$("#message").val()+'</message>\
    </InsertIntoContacts>\
  </soap:Body>\
</soap:Envelope>';

    $.ajax({
        url: "host/contacts.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        data: soapRequset,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "xml",
        processData: false,
        success: function (xData, status) { alert(status) },
        error: function (xData, status, req) {
              alert(xData.status);
              alert(status);
              alert(req);
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: Exactly what does that error says??

Comment: First alert says error. Second alert says undefined

Comment: check what status code you are getting, i.e. `404`, `400` or `500`?!

Comment: I modified the error function . 1st alert shows 0. Second shows error . Third is just blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research I found that ajax error code `0` means that jQuery is unable to reach the url . So I hosted the web service in the same web site . Now its working. The modified ajax call is below:

```
function sendMsg() {
var soapRequest = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">\
        <soap:Body>\
          <InsertIntoContacts xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">\
            <name>'+ $("#name").val() + '</name>\
            <email>' + $("#email").val() + '</email>\
            <message>' + $("#message").val() + '</message>\
         </InsertIntoContacts>\
       </soap:Body>\
   </soap:Envelope>';
$.ajax({
    url: "../WebService/contacts.asmx",
    type: "POST",
    data: soapRequest,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "xml",
    processData: false,
    success: function (xData, status) { alert(status) },
    error: function (xData, status) { alert(status); }
});
}
```

Comment: due to same origin policy of browser you will not be able to call other website using client scripts... although you should be able to do it using server side code like C#.  To get service access through scripting service needs to configure for CORS.

Comment: Ohh.. ok.. Thats why i was unable to reach the web service hosted in another web site and i was getting code 0  . Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

check this out [using jquery to directly call aspnet ajax page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)